# pthread_create failed and returned -1 (or 4294967295)

Tags: c, multithreading, openssl

I'm trying to reproduce an example from *Network Security with OpenSSL* (by Chandra *et al*). The program consists of `client.c` `server.c` `common.h` and `common.c`. `client.c` simply creates a connection to the server on port 6012 and reads data from `stdin` and then send those data to the server. The `server.c` reads data from socket and writes it back out to `stdout`.

The problem is that `server.c` always get stuck in `if(BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)` at line 62 and never gets data sent from `client.c`, which runs perfectly fine. I later found the problem is that `pthread_create(...)` at line 66 ( which is defined as `THREAD_CREATE(...)` in `common.h`) failed and it returned `4294967295`. Because `THREAD_CREATE(...)` failed, the program never get a chance to run `do_server_loop` in `server_thread(...)`, which explains why the server never got the data from client.

How should I interpret the return values from `pthread_create` and how should I fix it?
PS. I later used `strerror` to convert `4294967295` and it returned "Unknown error".

Any help will be much appreciated!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is `server.c`:

```
#include "common.h" 
void do_server_loop(BIO *conn)
{
    int err, nread;
    char buf[80];

    do
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "server_loop executed.\n");
        for(nread = 0; nread < sizeof(buf); nread += err)
        {
            err = BIO_read(conn, buf + nread, sizeof(buf) - nread);
            if(err <= 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
    }
    while (err > 0);
}

void THREAD_CC server_thread(void *arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "server_thread(void *arg) executed.\n");
    BIO *client = (BIO *)arg;
#ifndef WIN32
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
#endif
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection opened.\n");
    do_server_loop(client);
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection closed.\n");

    BIO_free(client);
    ERR_remove_state(0);
#ifdef WIN32
    _endthread();
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BIO     *acc, *client;
    int thread_create_result;
    THREAD_TYPE tid;

    init_OpenSSL();

    acc = BIO_new_accept(PORT);
    if(!acc){
        int_error("Error creating server socket");
    }

    if(BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0){
        int_error("Error binding server socket");   
    }
    for(;;)
    {
        if(BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0){
            int_error("Error accepting connection");
        }
        client = BIO_pop(acc);
        thread_create_result = THREAD_CREATE(tid, server_thread, client);
        if(thread_create_result != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "THREAD_CREATE failed! returns: %s.\n", \
                                            strerror(thread_create_result));
            fprintf(stderr, "thread_create_result has the value: %u.\n", \
                                            thread_create_result);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    BIO_free(acc);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is `common.h`

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/objects.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#ifndef WIN32
#include <pthread.h>
#define THREAD_CC *
#define THREAD_TYPE         pthread_t
#define THREAD_CREATE(tid, entry, arg)  pthread_create(&(tid), NULL, \
                                   (entry), (arg))
#else
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#define THREAD_CC              __cdecl
#define THREAD_TYPE            DWORD
#define THREAD_CREATE(tid, entry, arg) do { _beginthread((entry), 0, (arg));\
                        (tid) = GetCurrentThreadId();\
                       } while (0)
#endif

#define PORT    "6012"      //port
#define SERVER  "10.1.251.24"   //server address
#define CLIENT  "10.1.21.46"    //client address

#define int_error(msg) handle_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
void handle_error(const char *file, int lineno, const char *msg);

void init_OpenSSL(void);
```

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OPENSSLDIR = /usr/local/ssl
#CFLAGS = -g -Wall -W -I${OPENSSLDIR}/include -O2 -D_REENTRANT -D__EXTENSIONS__  
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -W -I${OPENSSLDIR}/include -O2

RPATH = -R${OPENSSLDIR}/lib
#LD = ${RPATH} -L${OPENSSLDIR}/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lsocket -lnsl -lpthread
LD = -L${OPENSSLDIR}/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lsocket -lnsl -pthread

OBJS = common.o

PROGS = server

all: ${PROGS}

server: server.o ${OBJS}
        ${CC} server.o ${OBJS} -o server ${LD}


clean:;
        ${RM} ${PROGS} *.ln *.BAK *.bak *.o
```

Comment: Are you sure the return value is from pthread_create? I want to know if you have compiled with -DWIN32 as its under #ifndef.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the 4294967295 is returned from pthread_create and I later used strerror to convert the error number and just got "Unknown error". I don't think I compiled with -DWIN32...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `-D_REENTRANT` on compile command lines and `-lpthread` on the link command line.
`-D_REENTRANT` will tell C/C++ libraries that your program is in multithread mode and `-lpthread` just load the shared library libpthread.so at runtime. I found this at [William Garrison's POSIX threads tutorial](http://www.mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/pthreads_tutorial/) and [this link](http://www.unixguide.net/sun/faq/5.38.shtml).

Here is the Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OPENSSLDIR = /usr/local/ssl
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -W -I${OPENSSLDIR}/include -O2 -D_REENTRANT -D__EXTENSIONS__  

RPATH = -R${OPENSSLDIR}/lib
LD = ${RPATH} -L${OPENSSLDIR}/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lsocket -lnsl -lpthread

OBJS = common.o

PROGS = server

all: ${PROGS}

server: server.o ${OBJS}
        ${CC} server.o ${OBJS} -o server ${LD}


clean:;
        ${RM} ${PROGS} *.ln *.BAK *.bak *.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(thread_create_result = !0){
```

to

```
if(thread_create_result != 0){
```

Besides, you can use *[strerror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strerror/)* function to convert error code to human-readable form.

Comment: @adf88: thanks! I updated my code and added "fprintf(stderr, "THREAD_CREATE failed! returns: %s.\n", strerror(thread_create_result));" at line 68. Here is what the program returned: 
THREAD_CREATE failed! returns: Unknown error.
thread_create_result has the value: 4294967295.

Comment: @adf88: I checked the listed error codes from pthread_create but couldn't find the one I got. Thanks!

Comment: 4294967295 is just the unsigned version of -1.

Comment: @Amardeep: so what does it mean? I just used strerr(-1) and it still returned "Unknown error."

Comment: @Amardeep: I also used strerror(errno) and it returned "Error 0". I got really confused :(

Comment: @Z.Zen - strerror() is for C library error codes, not POSIX error codes.  The return value of pthread_create() is one of several values defined in pthread.h:  EAGAIN, EINVAL, and EPERM.  Check the man page of your target system to see the comprehensive list.

Comment: @Amardeep: I managed to fix the problem by adding -D_REENTRANT on compile command line and -lthread on the link command line. The reason why my program did nothing when it hit pthread_create is because I didn't tell C libraries that the program is using multi-thread mode. Now it's working perfectly!

Comment: @Z.Zen - Assuming you are using gcc, the only parameter you should provide is `-pthread`, which generates all flags necessary for multi-threaded operation.  The problem may have been that you were only using `-lpthread` (note the letter l) which only links in the library but doesn't set the flags.  You managed to do it manually, but that may not set **all** flags needed by a platform.

Comment: You get -1 because you assigned `!0` to `thread_create_result` which is -1

Comment: @adf88: I updated the server.c right after you posted your answer. It stopped returning 1 but it started returning 4294967295, which "is just the unsigned version of -1", according to Amardeep. But I figured out how to do it and it now works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Amardeep: I tried '-pthread' but my gcc compiler returned 'gcc: unrecognized option `-pthread''. I'm using gcc 3.4.6. I just posted my Makefile above. The commented lines are those I used before. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using gcc under cygwin?  That doesn't support -pthread.

Comment: @Amardeep: no. I'm just using gcc under Solaris 9 terminal.